# care-o-bot simulation extremely slow

Tags: ros, gazebo, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to simulate care-o-bot in gazebo running electric with ubuntu 10.4.

Although not all of the cob_dashboard buttons seem to work, the ones that do are *extremely* slow.  Simply extending the tray takes almost 2 minutes.  Is this to be expected?  Also, can anyone suggest why the other buttons (particularly, the base motions) don't seem to do anything?

Thanks,
Paul.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11240/care-o-bot-simulation-extremely-slow/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-19**:
Hi Hsu.  I'm running (verbatim) the commands given at:  http://www.care-o-bot-research.org/software/tutorials/move-the-robot-in-simulation.  I've tried running with both the dashboard and with the teleop keyboard commands (but not at the same time).  I get the similarly slow response in both cases.  Would appreciate any help you can give me.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-18**:
can you provide more details as to what you are running, what commands were used to launch/control the simulation?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In electric, I am getting about ~0.35Xreal-time on my desktop (i7 quad), if you are getting 0.03xreal-time, something is wrong.  Can you try profiling it with your favorite profiler (e.g. valgrind) and post some results?

The 0.35Xreal-time should be improvable too, but let start with the 0.03X problem?

I tried turning off the kinect camera by commenting out following line in the urdf

```
<xacro:cob_kinect_gazebo_v0 name="${name}" ros_topic="${ros_topic}"/>
```

and I am getting about 1.4Xreal-time.  Taking a closer look, the current code was using gazebo_ros_block_laser plugin with 160X160 configuration.  A better way to implement this is to use the gazebo_ros_openni_kinect plugin, for example, update your kinect.gazebo.xacro file to look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
      xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
      xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
      xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  
<xacro:macro name="cob_kinect_gazebo_v0" params="name ros_topic">

  <gazebo reference="${name}_frame">

    <sensor:camera name="${name}_sensor">
      <imageFormat>R8G8B8</imageFormat>
      <imageSize>320 240</imageSize>
      <hfov>57</hfov>
      <nearClip>0.01</nearClip>
      <farClip>5</farClip>
      <updateRate>1.0</updateRate>
      <baseline>0.2</baseline>
      <controller:gazebo_ros_openni_kinect name="${name}_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>1.0</updateRate>
        <imageTopicName>/${ros_topic}/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <pointCloudTopicName>/${ros_topic}/points</pointCloudTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>/${ros_topic}/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>/${name}_frame</frameName>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
        <distortion_k1>0.00000001</distortion_k1>
        <distortion_k2>0.00000001</distortion_k2>
        <distortion_k3>0.00000001</distortion_k3>
        <distortion_t1>0.00000001</distortion_t1>
        <distortion_t2>0.00000001</distortion_t2>
      </controller:gazebo_ros_openni_kinect>
    </sensor:camera>

    <material value="Gazebo/Red" />
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>

</xacro:macro>

</root>
```

and you should see drastic improvements in speed.

Aside from performance gains, fundamentally, a depth camera like Kinect is better modeled by a gazebo_ros_camera/gazebo_ros_openni_kinect than gazebo_ros_block_laser.  In gazebo_ros_block_laser, the scan angles are constant as you make a horizontal or vertical scan, but for kinect, you actually want equal size pixels for each ray trace, which means the angle between rays as you scan vertically or horizontally is not constant.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-24**:
Commenting out the kinect line give me (initially) about 0.8 real time.  However, this decreases to about 0.5 after a few seconds. Using the kinect plugin gives me about 0.5.  If I also add 2dnav, performance degrades to about 0.3.  All these cases are better than I was previously experiencing... but 2dnav is still slow to look at.

**Comment by [RobMichael](https://answers.ros.org/users/1097/robmichael/) on 2011-09-19**:
Thanks a lot! On my laptop commenting out the kinect line gains same factor than for you, now running 0.15. I'll try your xacro file and do a oprofile soon, but need a lot of things get done before leaving to iros. So maybe that will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We do have the same problem here on several machines. Even a powerful 4 core machine with nvidia graphics (ubuntu 10.4 64bit, electric) runs only at 0.03xrealtime. It was at least 10 times faster with diamondback. Interestingly enough the same speed is shown on a i5 laptop with intel graphics. So one could speculate that it is somehow controlled to that speed, not limited by the hardware.

I talked to some people at IPA and they have seen this also, but only sporadicly. They can get rid of that by starting again. One person remembers to have seen this under diamondback also, but feels that occurecne increased under electric. For us it keeps beeing slow for every start.

Any ideas how to attac this and narrow down the reason?

For the base motion: you need to start cob_2dnav. Only then commanding base motion works. You can then move the base also from rviz by setting target goals.

---

Originally posted by [RobMichael](https://answers.ros.org/users/1097/robmichael/) with karma: 11 on 2011-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-19**:
Thanks for the feedback RobMichael and for the tip on starting base motion.  I'm curious as to why gazebo/ROS is such a slow simulator.  Is it generally true that ROS/gazebo do not produce real time simulations?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the 0.03Xreal-time issue happen with the plugin substitution suggested above?

Also, can you try profiling a run using valgrind?  e.g. update your gazebo node to look like this:

```
   <node alaunch-prefix="valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes --simulate-cache=yes --collect-jumps=yes " name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(optenv SIMX) $(find cob_gazebo_worlds)/common/worlds/empty.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
```

roslaunch cob simulation, let it run for a while.  In your ros log directory (usually `~/.ros`) there should be a file that looks like `calgrind.out.[pid]`, run kcachegrind on it to see some nice plots.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1